# Google Cloud Pub Sub StreamingPull does not work correctly

Tags: c#, .net, google-cloud-pubsub

Does anybody know, does Google Cloud PubSub client support StreamingPull?

This code:

```cs
SubscriberServiceApiClient client = SubscriberServiceApiClient.Create();
SubscriberServiceApiClient.StreamingPullStream stream = client.StreamingPull();
await stream.WriteAsync(new StreamingPullRequest { SubscriptionAsSubscriptionName = subscriptionName });

Task pullingTask = Task.Run(async () =>
{
    AsyncResponseStream<StreamingPullResponse> responseStream = stream.GetResponseStream();
    while (await responseStream.MoveNextAsync())
    {
        StreamingPullResponse response = responseStream.Current;
        Console.WriteLine("Received streaming response");
        foreach (ReceivedMessage message in response.ReceivedMessages)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"Message text: {message.Message.Data.ToStringUtf8()}");
        }
    }
});

publisher.Publish(topicName, new[] { new PubsubMessage { Data = ByteString.CopyFromUtf8("Message 1") } });
publisher.Publish(topicName, new[] { new PubsubMessage { Data = ByteString.CopyFromUtf8("Message 2") } });
publisher.Publish(topicName, new[] { new PubsubMessage { Data = ByteString.CopyFromUtf8("Message 3") } });

await stream.WriteCompleteAsync();
```

Throwing the next exception:

```
    Grpc.Core.RpcException
  HResult=0x80131500
  Message=Status(StatusCode=Internal, Detail="A service error has occurred. Please retry your request. If the error persists, please report it. [code=e8c0]")
  Source=System.Private.CoreLib
```

This line is a problem : `while (await responseStream.MoveNextAsync())`

Comment: Is there any reason you're using the low-level API rather than `SubscriberClient`, which is generally easier to use and higher performance? (There *are* some reasons, but I can't tell whether they apply here...)

Comment: I do not have any specific reason for that except the only ```SubscriberServiceApiClient``` has ```StreamingPull``` method. If I want to use the full potential of PubSub, streamingPull is a better solution.
Ok, I have created ```SubscriberClient``` and started consuming messages by ```await client1.StartAsync((msg, cancellationToken) =>...```. But if ```StreamingPull``` is deprecated it probably should not be part of API, it is my opinion.

Comment: SubscriberClient uses `StreamingPull` behind the scenes. It's not that StreamingPull is deprecated - I suspect there may be something going on with how you're using it. But the point is if you don't need to use the lower level API, it's simpler not to anyway.

Comment: If you want to see the full detail of what SubscriberClient is doing, here's the source: https://github.com/googleapis/google-cloud-dotnet/blob/master/apis/Google.Cloud.PubSub.V1/Google.Cloud.PubSub.V1/SubscriberClient.cs. Note the calls to StreamingPull. I *suspect* the problem with your original code was the lack of specifying StreamAckDeadlineSeconds, but I don't know for sure.

Comment: Ok, thanks @JonSkeet. ```SubscriberClient.StartAsync``` is good enough for now.